# Issue using new image added to ImageList in TreeView VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having trouble using a new image that I put in my image list programatically. All old images work fine. The new image I am trying to use in my TreeView is Comment.bmp.

```
Public Sub loadImageList()

il_ForTreeview.ListImages.Clear

il_ForTreeview.ImageHeight = sldr_treeSize.Value
il_ForTreeview.ImageWidth = sldr_treeSize.Value

    With il_ForTreeview.ListImages
       .Add , "IntermediateEvent", LoadPicture(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\icons\IntermediateEvent.bmp")
       .Add , "Outcome", LoadPicture(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\icons\Outcome.bmp")
       .Add , "EndState", LoadPicture(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\icons\EndState.bmp")
       .Add , "Comment", LoadPicture(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\icons\Comment.bmp")
   End With

End Sub
```

Now whenever a node has an ID_Type of 2 it should have its image set to the Comment.bmp.

```
Private Sub addChildren(tv As TreeView, nodParent As Node, rsReqs As DAO.Recordset, lngParentID As Long)
   ...
      Set nodX = tv.Nodes.Add(nodParent, tvwChild, genReqNodeID(rsReqs!PK_Main), Left(rsReqs!mem_Req, 200)) 
      Select Case rsReqs!ID_Types
         Case 1 'Head
            nodX.Image = "Head"
         Case 2 'Comment
            nodX.Image = "Comment"
         Case 3 'IntermediateEvent
            nodX.Image = "IntermediateEvent"      
         Case 4 'EndState
            nodX.Image = "EndState"      
      End Select
      ...
   Loop
End Sub
```

And I definitely have the Comment.bmp file in my icons folder. The problem seems to be that the program doesn't recognize the name of the new image because if I change the new file to be named one of the others like "EndState" the image loads in fine. Is microsoft access cacheing the old image list??

The error i get is

```
frm_Phases Form_Current 35601 Element not found
```